# AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'in_waiting

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, python-3.4

I am trying to receive data from USB OBD and I am using raspberry Pi3.. here is my simple code :

```
import obd

connection = obd.OBD() # auto-connects to USB or RF port

cmd = obd.commands.RPM # select an OBD command (sensor)

response = connection.query(cmd) # send the command

print(response) # "2410 RPM"
```

When I started to run the code I get this error:

```
: AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'in_waiting'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Per the documentation of [pyserial v3.0](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html), `in_waiting` "changed to property from `inWaiting()`". This leads me to believe that your `pyserial` library is too old for the `odb` library (ie. odb is using the pyserial library in a way that your version can't handle; it doesn't have the `in_waiting` property that `odb` is looking for, instead it has the older `inWaiting()` method instead).

You can check your version of pyserial with:

```
>>> import serial
>>> serial.VERSION
'2.6'
```

If you're not at version 3.x, you will need to upgrade the `pyserial` library.

Comment: thanks for your response .. yes my pyserial version is 2.6 but when i am upgrading pyserial by 'python -m pip install pyserial --upgrade' it tells me that i am using the newest version (2.6)..And attribute error only appear to me when i ran it on python 3.4 but when i use python 2.7 the code is working good